# How to copy a line from one file and replace the line in another?

Tags: shell-script

Looking to be able to have a part in a script that pulls the shadow file entry from one computer, and then find that user's entry on another computer and replace that line (to update their password on multiple computers).

Note that this is part of a user creation script, so the users will be created on each computer first, then adding a password on the server, which would then copy it to the other workstations.

Comment: You should use `usermod` rather than manually edit `/etc/{passwd,shadow}`

Comment: If the password is coming from the server then that means that the computers are authenticating via the server. With that being said, why do you need to create the users on the computers? It would help if you'd be more clear on your setup and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Script is being run on the server, there is no authentication via the network. Presently, we have to add users and set their passwords on each computer, trying to do it from one instead.

Comment: Failing the ability to e.g. use LDAP for this, have you considered using ansible? You can store hashes on one machine and push them to as many target machines as needed ...

Answer (score 1):

While agreeing with the above comments that there are a lot more simpler ways to handle this, here is a bit of help with the actual question:

```
$MY_USER="anything"
HASH=$(ssh <source_server> "cat /etc/shadow | grep ^$MY_USER:" | awk -F: '{print $2}')
ssh <target_server> "echo '$MY_USER:$HASH' | chpasswd -e"
```

Replace the `MY_USER` variable for your particular user and loop through your servers with the last row of the script.

Some other comments:

1. You should make sure that all of your servers use the same password encoding (Also creating a backup from the entry being replaced, just in case).
2. If you do not have access to the root password, and have no nopasswd sudo rules set up, `sudo -S` could be useful.
3. Make sure you have other ways of access before changing the password.

Comment: This looks to be precisely what I was looking for, thank you!